# Silverlight and memory

Tags: silverlight, memory

We have an enterprise silverlight application (Silverlight Version 5.1.10411.0) that has a memory issue.

When the silverlight application runs on a fast computer (intel I7 and >4 GB memory) the memory usage is between 500 ~ 800mb but when it runs on a slower computer (intel I5 or I3 and  <4GB memory) GC seems to be never called and the memory usage keeps increase and increase untill it crashes the system.

I tried to call GC manually but it doesn't work on a slower computer.

I tested out with 8 different computers but the results are same.

If the memory usage behaviors are same for the all computers I could suspect the memory leaks, but how come it only happends on the slower computers?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ClientHttp and setting AllowWriteStreamBuffering to false? There is a bunch of bugs with this feature, including causing an uncontrolled memory leak (at least on Mac). Otherwise, it may be a bug in your code. It's easy to have memory leaks in C#. Just don't release references (and there's a number of tricky cases of invisible references involving event handlers and other things). There's nothing the GC can do. However, that wouldn't explain the difference in behavior.